# not executing shellscript file properly using cron

Tags: shell, cron

I have query about shell script

```
MYIPPADDR=`ifconfig ppp0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}' | sed 's/addr://'`
if [ ! -z "$MYIPPADDR" -a "$MYIPPADDR" != "" ];
```

where MYIPPADDR, i am getting my pc ip address and i am checking condition that weather it is null or blank and the script file which i am using is executes properly in console but executes again and again by crontab. So could not able to trace it out where the problem is. Can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

cron runs in a very limited environment: the PATH is something very basic like `/bin:/usr/bin`

You need to provide the full path to ifconfig: `/usr/sbin/ifconfig` (probably)

---

Note that `[ ! -z "$var" ]` and `[ "$var" != "" ]` test *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: Hi glenn jackman,

At frist thanks for your reply and what you suggested is worked. i should give proper path of ifconfig. is there any way that we can put some log in shell script which will executed by crontab and we can trace where the problem is.

thanks
rabi

Comment: look in /var/log/syslog